# Protecting from LFI-like vulnerabilities when the file doesn't exist yet

Tags: php, security, web, realpath

If a user was requesting a file on a service, I could normally protect them from accessing documents outside the scope of what I want by using PHP's [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and ensuring it is under the root directory. Such as like this:

```
$path = realpath($_GET['path']);
// Protect against LFI vulnerabilities
if (substr($path, 0, strlen($root)) == $root)
{
    // safe
}
```

However, realpath() only works on files *that already exist*.
What if I want to ensure that the location the user is about to have my script write to is under the root?

I can't use realpath(), should I just check and strip out '..' references? 
Or is there a better way?

Comment: You could `basename` the path, and check if that's in your root. I assume that your users will be writing to an existing upload directory, or something such — if not, that obviously won't work.

Comment: The application will raise an error if they try to write to a directory that does not exist, so it is safe to assume that the directory will exist. I am aware of `basename`, but not how that would be helpful. Are you able to give a code example?

Comment: Whoops, I meant dirname: `if (substr(dirname($path, 0, strlen($root)) == $root)`.

Comment: From the docs: "dirname() operates naively on the input string, and is not aware of the actual filesystem, or path components such as '..'", I also tried it and verified that it does not resolve components like '..'

Comment: If the user controls what directory the files go under, then you could just strip out any "../" characters from the input, and work with that. If you control what directory they upload to, just check for a valid filename - [a-z][A-Z][-_] should be all you allow, with the provision for an extension. Makes your job a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I think that's the only solution. If you make that as an answer, I'll select it if noone has any other ideas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking if realpath(dirname($file)) is under the root directory?

```
$dir = $path;
$found = false;

while ($dir) {
    $dir = dirname($dir);
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (strpos(realpath($dir), $root) === 0) {
        $found = true;
    }

    break;
}

var_dump($found);
```

Comment: Btw: your method of checking returns true only when $path == $root, so I guess it's not very correct